# I want to read from text file that displays which character appears most or least often (keyboard or text file) ? :)

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[1000], ch;
   int i, frequency = 0;

   printf("Enter a string: ");
   gets(str);

   printf("Enter a character to find the frequency: ");
   scanf("%c",&ch);

   for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
   {
       if(ch == str[i])
           ++frequency;
   }

   printf("Frequency of %c = %d", ch, frequency);

   return 0;
```

I figured that the frequency of characters code I came up with is similar. How to implement the character which appears more / less often in standard input or text file?

Also, should I use `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt")` for reading normal text files for this code?

EDIT: Have to use Switch /M for most often and /L for least often.

Comment: `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt")` are you sure that is C?

Comment: A friend of mine recommended me. Not sure that's why I asked.

Comment: Yeah, but that is `Java`. A completely different language. That wont work with C.

Comment: You can read upon [`fopen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm), [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) for C.

Comment: You do not need to store all the `chars` from the file, count the number of char in the file, the number of occurences of each char (an array of count of characters in the file).

Comment: Use the `gets` function only if you decide to do so after reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used .

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt")/ C# as well :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a good start...

```
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[1000], ch,lookup_Chars[256];
   int i, frequency = 0;
   char counter;
   printf("Enter a string: ");
   gets(str);

   printf("Enter a character to find the frequency: ");
   scanf("%c",&ch);

   for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
   {
       lookup_Chars[str[i]]++;
   }
  for(counter = 0; counter<sizeof(lookup_Chars); counter++)
   {
        printf("Frequency of %c = %d", counter, lookup_Chars[counter]);
   }


   return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you :) . But I have an edit. EDIT: Have to use Switch /M for most often and /L for least often.

Answer (score 0):

Never, never, never use `gets`. It is so insecure and so susceptible to buffer overrun, it has been removed from the C standard library. Use `fgets` instead, just be aware that `fgets` will read and include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer it fills (just as all legitimate *line oriented* input functions do, such as POSIX `getline`). This prevents leaving a `'\n'` unread in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) following each user input.

You risk *Undefined Behavior* because you do not *validate* the contents of `str` in any way and then you fail to validate the **return** of `scanf` to insure a character was read. (the user could cancel input in either case by generating an `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on *nix systems of with <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze).

Further, you must understand that `scanf` will leave characters in the input buffer (as will `fgets` if the line is longer than the amount of storage you have allocated). That is one of the most common pitfalls new C programmers fall victim to. (failing to validate a complete line of input was read and failing to handle characters that remain in the input buffer)

When taking user input with `fgets` (which is recommended), since it reads and includes the '`\n'` in the buffer it fills, you simply check the length of the buffer read with `strlen` and then make sure the last character is a `'\n'`.

`scanf` is full of pitfalls when used for user input. While it can be used, if used correctly with it's return validated and any remaining characters emptied from `stdin` before your next call to `scanf`, you have to approach it use that way. In your case `ch` is the last input for your file, but try taking input for `ch` before reading the string and see what happens...

Putting it altogether, and adding validations for both `str` and `ch`, and adding additional comments in-line below, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 1024       /* if you need a constant, define one */

int main (void) {

    int frequency = 0;
    char str[MAXS] = "", 
        *p = str,           /* pointer to str */
        ch;  

    printf ("Enter a string: ");

    if (fgets (str, MAXS, stdin)) {         /* validate input received */
        size_t len = strlen (str);          /* get length of str */
        if (len && str[len - 1] != '\n') {  /* validate all input read */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXS-2);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* if fgets failed - user generated EOF to cancel */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input (EOF).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter a character to find the frequency: ");
    if (scanf ("%c", &ch) != 1) {   /* note: chars will remain in stdin */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (*p != '\n')      /* just use a pointer to str */
        if (*p++ == ch)     /* compare to ch and increment to next char */
            frequency++;    /* increment frequency if they are equal */

    printf ("\nFrequency of %c = %d\n", ch, frequency);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you could declare `char ch[3] = "";` and use `fgets` to read `fgets (ch, sizeof ch, stdin)` and then simply compare `if (*p++ == *ch)` to prevent leaving the '`\n'` in `stdin` (but you would still need to validate that it was the final character read, and if not manually empty `stdin`))

**Exammple Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/freqofc
Enter a string: a man a plan a canal panama
Enter a character to find the frequency: a

Frequency of a = 10

$ ./bin/freqofc
Enter a string: a man a plan a canal panama
Enter a character to find the frequency: p

Frequency of p = 2

$ ./bin/freqofc
Enter a string: a man a plan a canal panama
Enter a character to find the frequency: z

Frequency of z = 0
```

Look things over, think about the validations that were made, and let me know if you have any further questions.

---

**Using a Frequency Array to Capture Count of all Chars**

Using a *frequency array* allows you to capture the frequency of all characters (or the independent count of any element of a set). Essentially, you use an array **initialized to zero** with one element for each member of the set you want to count the frequency of each occurrence. Since there are `128` [ASCII Characters](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can simply use an array of `128` elements, e.g. `int frequency[128] = {0};`.

If you look at the link provided, you see the ASCII value of each character corresponds to a value between `0-127`, so when looping over each character in the input string, if you increment the array index that corresponds to the character, you end up with the total count for each character in its corresponding element. For example, if `p` is a pointer to the beginning of `str`, then you can loop over each character in the string capturing their frequency in the `frequency[*p]` element of the array:

```
while (*p != '\n') {
    frequency[*p]++;   /* increments element corresponding to char *p */
    p++;               /* note: cast to (int)*p intentional omitted   */
}
```

Now that you have the frequency for every character stored in the `frequency`, you can simply loop over the elements you are concerned about to determine `max/min`, etc... ***Note:*** the normal printable characters begin with `'space'` (ASCII `32`, or hex `0x20`) and end with `'~'` (ASCII `126` or hex 0x7e`). So just limit your check of values to the printable range, e.g.

```
    /* loop over printable characters (see ASCII Chart), for max/min */
    for (int i = ' '; i <= '~'; i++) {
        /* require a frequency of at least 1 for min */
        if (frequency[i] && frequency[i] < min) {
            min = frequency[i];     /* save least frequent count */
            minc = i;               /* save least frequent char */
        }
        if (frequency[i] > max) {   /* just find max */
            max = frequency[i];     /* save same for max */
            maxc = i;
        }
    }
```

(**note:** you can further micro-divide ranges for only lowercase, uppercase, digits, etc..)

Putting that altogether, you can do something similar to the following to report the number of occurrence if the wanted char, the max occurring char, the min occurring char (and then summarize by dumping the frequency of all chars):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXS 1024   /* if you need a constant, define one */
#define NASCII 128  /* number of ASCII chars (includes non-printing) */

int main (void) {

    int frequency[NASCII] = {0},
        max = INT_MIN,
        min = INT_MAX;
    char str[MAXS] = "",
        *p = str,           /* pointer to str */
        ch, 
        minc = 0, 
        maxc = 0;

    printf ("Enter a string: ");

    if (fgets (str, MAXS, stdin)) {         /* validate input received */
        size_t len = strlen (str);          /* get length of str */
        if (len && str[len - 1] != '\n') {  /* validate all input read */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXS-2);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* if fgets failed - user generated EOF to cancel */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input (EOF).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter a character to find the frequency: ");
    if (scanf ("%c", &ch) != 1) {   /* note: chars will remain in stdin */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (*p != '\n')              /* just use a pointer to str */
        frequency[(int)*p++]++;     /* increment element representing ch */

    /* loop over printable characters (see ASCII Chart), for max/min */
    for (int i = ' '; i <= '~'; i++) {
        /* require a frequency of at least 1 for min */
        if (frequency[i] && frequency[i] < min) {
            min = frequency[i];     /* save least frequent count */
            minc = i;               /* save least frequent char */
        }
        if (frequency[i] > max) {   /* just find max */
            max = frequency[i];     /* save same for max */
            maxc = i;
        }
    }

    /* ouput requested char freq, and max/min chars */
    printf ("\nFrequency of %c = %d\n"
            "least frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n"
            " most frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
            ch, frequency[(int)ch], minc, min, maxc, max);

    /* output frequency of all printable chars */
    printf ("frequency of all printable characters:\n");
    for (int i = ' '; i < '~'; i++)
        if (frequency[i])
            printf ("  '%c'  :  %d\n", i, frequency[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Exammple Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/freqofc2
Enter a string: a man a plan a canal panama
Enter a character to find the frequency: m

Frequency of m = 2
least frequent occurrence: c = 1
 most frequent occurrence: a = 10

frequency of all printable characters:
  ' '  :  6
  'a'  :  10
  'c'  :  1
  'l'  :  2
  'm'  :  2
  'n'  :  4
  'p'  :  2
```

---

**Adding /L or /M Switches for Least/Max Occurrences**

To add command line switches, for a minimum number in a known order, you can simply use the allowable *argument count* and *argument vector* parameters to `main()`, e.g. `int main (int argc, char **argv)`. Example:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    /* validate "/L" or "/M" provided as an argument */
    if (argc != 2 || (argv[1][1] != 'L' && argv[1][1] != 'M')) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, req'd /M or /L.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

To test and output either the least or minimum, you simply test which character is present and act accordingly, e.g.

```
    ...
    if (argv[1][1] == 'L')  /* output requested lease or max */
        printf ("requested least frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
                minc, min);
    else
        printf ("requested most frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
                maxc, max);
```

Putting that together an a complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXS 1024   /* if you need a constant, define one */
#define NASCII 128  /* number of ASCII chars (includes non-printing) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int frequency[NASCII] = {0},
        max = INT_MIN,
        min = INT_MAX;
    char str[MAXS] = "",
        *p = str,           /* pointer to str */
        ch, 
        minc = 0, 
        maxc = 0;

    /* validate "/L" or "/M" provided as an argument */
    if (argc != 2 || (argv[1][1] != 'L' && argv[1][1] != 'M')) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, req'd /M or /L.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter a string: ");

    if (fgets (str, MAXS, stdin)) {         /* validate input received */
        size_t len = strlen (str);          /* get length of str */
        if (len && str[len - 1] != '\n') {  /* validate all input read */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line exceeds %d chars.\n", MAXS-2);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* if fgets failed - user generated EOF to cancel */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input (EOF).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Enter a character to find the frequency: ");
    if (scanf ("%c", &ch) != 1) {   /* note: chars will remain in stdin */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: user canceled input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (*p != '\n')              /* just use a pointer to str */
        frequency[(int)*p++]++;     /* increment element representing ch */

    /* loop over printable characters (see ASCII Chart), for max/min */
    for (int i = ' '; i <= '~'; i++) {
        /* require a frequency of at least 1 for min */
        if (frequency[i] && frequency[i] < min) {
            min = frequency[i];
            minc = i;
        }
        if (frequency[i] > max) {   /* just find max */
            max = frequency[i];
            maxc = i;
        }
    }

    /* ouput requested char freq, and max/min chars */
    printf ("\nFrequency of %c = %d\n"
            "least frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n"
            " most frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
            ch, frequency[(int)ch], minc, min, maxc, max);

    if (argv[1][1] == 'L')  /* output requested lease or max */
        printf ("requested least frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
                minc, min);
    else
        printf ("requested most frequent occurrence: %c = %d\n\n",
                maxc, max);

    /* output frequency of all printable chars */
    printf ("frequency of all printable characters:\n");
    for (int i = ' '; i < '~'; i++)
        if (frequency[i])
            printf ("  '%c'  :  %d\n", i, frequency[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you :) . But I have an edit.  EDIT: Have to use Switch /M for most often and /L for least often.

Comment: I'll drop an update showing the use of a frequency array.